# "LOADING" SOAP response to DOMDocument

Tags: vba, excel, soap

After some help from **stackoverflow experts** I have been able to successfully retrieve my response using SOAP. The below piece is how I received and stored the data. *This of course is not all the code. I just included this to show how I later reference the xml.*

```
With xmlhtp
webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace = "http://example.com/webservices/"
    .Open "POST", sUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "POST", "https://onesite.example.com/webservices/stuff.asmx HTTP/1.1"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", 100
    .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace & "RetrieveData"
    .send sEnv
    sResult = xmlhtp.statusText
    responseText = xmlhtp.responseText
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = .responseText
End With
Debug.Print responseText
```

Now I am having trouble parsing that out. This seems like it should be pretty simple but I get an error indicating that the responseText I receive above is not "loading" to xmlDOC. The following is at the beginning of the sub:

```
    Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim XDoc As Object
```

After the With End (shown above) my code looks like this:

```
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load (xmlhtp.responseText)
Set lists = XDoc.DocumentElement
Set getFirstChild = lists.FirstChild
Debug.Print getFirstChild.XML
Debug.Print getFirstChild.Text
```

On the line

```
Set getFirstChild = lists.FirstChild
```

I recieve the following error

```
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

When I look at the Local Variable window in VBA I can clearly see that nothing was assigned to xmlDoc. So I assume my problem is in XDoc.Load Line.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share `responseText` sample.

Comment: There is a lot of sensitive data in the responseText so I would prefer not to. Are you looking for particular content or formatting?

Comment: Since the question should contain [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's better to post some sample with sensitive data wiped out, and which reproduces the issue. So I'm looking how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: sounds like there are no child elements

Comment: While I do respect that completely, I am not even sure how I would do that in this case. When pasting to Word the doc stats tell me it is 7,118 words long. Of course I could take a lot of those words out but there are so many levels of child nodes I don't think I would end up giving you an accurate representation of the file. I will work on it though and see if it makes sense.. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @jstola - There are a lot of child nodes. My suspicion keeps gong back to if XDoc.Load can load the xml this way OR if the, to OmegaStripes point I believe, webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace.responseText does not have some sort of formatting the .load needs.

Comment: Try pasting the response text into an online validator like https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input If the XML isn't well-formed then it won't load into a DOM document. Also, use `DOMDocument60` instead of `DOMDocument` (which is a synonym for the older `DOMDocument30` type from MSXML, v3.0)

Comment: @barrowc, the OP  stated that the response text contains sensitive information

Comment: would you be able to replace the sensitive info in the response text with xxxx and post the response text?  even a screenshot with info redacted  ... i always wanted to say redacted .... lol

Comment: check this out https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html

Comment: Thanks @jstola for your response. I have gone over everything you suggested before coming back here. It seems the xmlhtp.responseText is somehow not formatted appropriately but I know this process is used by other vendors besides me. Any thoughts? I really cant paste the response because 1 - it is huge and 2 - there is a lot of sensitive data in it and redacting is just not really a good option.

Answer (score 1):

use `XDoc.LoadXML (xmlhtp.responseText)` instead of `XDoc.Load (xmlhtp.responseText)`

Comment: Could you add some more details around this?  Answers aren't just to help the original poster, they are also to help others learn.  Your post has probably been flagged for deletion for this reason.